# How to get template from the overrided woocommerce template files

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this reference [here](https://www.propatel.com/display-recent-orders-woocommerce/), that the creates shortcode to woocommerce my account order history.

From this code here `wc_get_template( 'myaccount/my-orders.php', array(`

how can I get the override template file in this?

I used `wc_get_template( '/wp-content/themes/my-theme/woocommerce/myaccount/my-orders.php', array(`

also did use the full url then `/wp-content/...`

But it won't get the override file.. Is there a proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**wc_get_template** is by default get override template file. So you have still an issue with getting the overridden template file so you need to add the below code in your function.php file by [ref](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256088/how-to-override-woocommerce-template-files).

```
function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```